# I Keep getting this warning when trying to submit my assignment warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress]

Tags: c++, space

What Really gets me upset is that this works on Visual Basic and not on my crappy school's server :(.

Note Mdestination and Mname are pointers

```
    if (Mdestination != nullptr && Mname != nullptr && Mname != "" && Mdestination != "") {
        strcpy_s(name, Mname);
        strcpy_s(destination, Mdestination);

    }


}
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the "" on my school server is there a substitute for "" instead of NULL?

Comment: If `Mdestination` is a `char*` then you should use `strcmp`. It is challenging to recommend something if the types aren't apparent.

Comment: You should use the same compiler settings used by your "crappy school's server." Because that server has the power to reject your code. :) Try add `-Waddress` to your "Visual Basic" environment.

Comment: *this works on Visual Basic* - No, it doesn't. Visual Basic doesn't have pointers, or `strcpy_s`.

Comment: `&& pointer != string literal`  is not doing what you think it is.  That is comparing the *memory address* of "" with the *memory address* of the pointer.  In C or C++ you need to use strlen().

Comment: lol sorry not visual basic visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe here you are mixing pointer arithmetic with string operations.

```
Mname != ""
```

Above line checks whether the pointer Mname and the literal "" are not at the same address. I believe your intent is to check whether the Mname does not point to an empty string. In that case, you could use

```
*Mname != '\0' // NUL could also be used instead of '\0'
```

Same goes with Mdestination.

Comment: Thank you very much